# How to add C# automatic calculations for a POCO entity in EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using DB first EF 6.1.3 with .NET 4.5.1, the T4 generated entities are POCO classes with generated auto properties. I would like to do some calculations (a calculated int field actually) before saving to the DB.

I could do this with an UPDATE trigger of course but now would like to prefer a C# algorithm. I've looked for what to override in DBContext and found nothing. The closest bet is `ValidateEntity(...)` but this smells me to use it something completely different what its name implies. (not talking about it seems not trivial how to access to the entity instance)

How and where to accomplish the auto calculations before update or better: upon property set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following, i.e. override SaveChanges.

```
public partial class MyEntities : ObjectContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Persists all updates to the data source with the specified System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="saveOptions">A System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions value that determines the behavior of the operation.</param>
    /// <returns>The number of objects in an System.Data.EntityState.Added, System.Data.EntityState.Modified, or 
    /// System.Data.EntityState.Deleted state when System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges() was called.</returns>
    public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions saveOptions)
    {
        List<Itinerary> itineraryLocations = ItineraryAddedDeletedMonitor.GetItineraryLocations(this);

        AlertManager.ObjectContextSavingChanges(this, null);
        int changes = base.SaveChanges(saveOptions);

        if (ItineraryAddedDeletedMonitor.ProcessItineraryLocations(this, itineraryLocations))
        {
            // new rows have been added
            base.SaveChanges(saveOptions);
        }

        return changes;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To access the entity instance, the objectStateEntries in the example below gets all Modified, Added and Deleted entities (alter as required):

```
IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntries = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted);

foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntries)
{
    if (!entry.IsRelationship && entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(CustomerTransfer) && entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        // Do some magic if the entity type is a CustomerTransfer that has been deleted.
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

... and variable objectContext is:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
```

Comment: Paul, how can I get the entity instance under update?

Answer (score 1):

For example sake you have a User with generated auto properties using database first. There will be a User.cs file generated within your .tt file. These are generated so there is no point changing them

What you could do is create a new file to contain metadata classes, in this example I will call it EntityAnnotations.cs, this reason I would call it this, is you can also use it to add annotations to your entity properties.

If the User generated class (generated from your existing database) had

```
 public partial class User
 {   
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
     public int CalculatedValue {get;set;}
 }
```

You could create this

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
public partial class User
{
     public int Calculate
     {
        get { return CalculatedValue;}
        set { CalculatedValue = value +1;}
     }
}
```

and then

```
public class UserMetadata
{
    //Fields from User requiring annotations
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }   
}
```

I have now enforced email address validation on a generated entity using the metadata. I also added a `Calculate` field using the partial class which will return CalculatedValue property from the generated class on `get` and set the calculatedValue  property to the result of the `Calculate` logic on `set`

Comment: James, is the calculated property (Calculated) stored in DB?

Comment: In the above example, no. As you are using database first. You could create the field on DB, update EDMX and it will then appear in the generated class. Then the partial you created within EntityAnnotations.cs can handle the calculation. I'll update example

Comment: If the field in the edmx, then the property automatically generated for it, and there is no possibility to create a custom getter...

Comment: There is, you create another partial class as shown above. You might choose not to return the database value and return something else entirely, which you can do in the custom getter. I agree there wont be many uses for one, but it can be created

Comment: James, in your sample code you duplicated the Calculated property in the not generated partial class this obviously a compile error... Also, the specification in the question is quite clear, and explained further in my prev comment: I need to store a calculated field in the DB  (just like and update trigger could work) and I would like to do the calculations in client side in C#

Comment: You are correct my previous edit added a compile error. I have fixed that now. I am not sure what you mean about using c# on the client side as its a backend language, but amendment I just made fixes that compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the SavingChanges event](http://ObjectContext.SavingChanges%20Event). If you use this technique you can look for entities of the desired type and in the desired state to modify them. The sample on the docs shows how to find those entities.